# Apple push notifications certificate expiry

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an app update and am building this new version completely from scratch. Am now in the process of setting up push notifications in the app.I can see that the app is already configured for push notifications but expiry for production push SSL certificate is Feb, 2012 [image: See image]

Does this means that the current version of app on the store wouldn't have working push notifications since the certificate is expired?

And what should be my next step if I want push notifications to work in the new vsersion. Revoke the old one and create new or shall I select Configure option on "Generate a new Production Push SSL certificate before your current one expires"

My only concern is that if the existing app has working push notifications they shouldn't get affected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This certificate is used on the server side, so if the certificate is expired, then server can't send push messages to Apple servers (probably the server receives an error while trying to connect to Apple servers).

Update:
Answer to the second part of your question, generate new certificate and install it on your server. Try to send test message and be sure that it works. Once you are done with testing revoke the old certificate and remove it from server to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: hi @alex is there any need to reupload the application once the certificate expired or need only change the certificate in the server?

Comment: @user:619434 can you give an answer?

Comment: Change the certificates on the server, no need to reupload the app.

Comment: Looks like renewing is a total server side work, but why does app's provisioning profile link to APNs cert? What is the APNs cert used for in apps? And after we replace new APNs cert in server, existing apps still contains old APNs cert, is it?

Comment: Apps do not contain APNs certs, as far as I understand. Apps are signed with iOS Distribution cert for App Store, APNs and VoIP certs are server side only.